# Where do paramaters go after getting passed to a flatten layer in tensorflow/keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I'm new to tensor flow. Just wondering why a shape of (7, 7, 64) with parameters of 51264 lose all its parameter when it gets past to a flatten layer. I assume that that's what flatten layers do, but just wondering what happens to the lost parameter; were those parameters of any use?

Comment: Flatten is applied to the output values of a layer, not to the layer itself, the weights or biases have nothing to do here.

Answer (score 0):

If by `parameters`, you mean the weights and biases in the layer (which I guess so), then those wouldn't pass anywhere. These parameters stick to layers and nodes. During training, we try to optimize these parameters using optimization algorithms and the backpropagation process. What would be passed is the input. So for example, if you pass a tensor with shape (Batch_size, 7, 7, 64) as input to a Flatten layer, then the output would have the shape of `[Batch_size, 7 * 7 * 64]`.